# How do I shrink row height to match the height of an inner table in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, height, row

I have an interesting Reporting Services scenario I am trying to accomplish in reporting services.  Here is my setup:

```
    TableCol    |    Table Col
----------------------------------
     Table      |    Textbox      
Row 1           |                 
Row 2           |                 
Row 3           |
```

All tables in this scenario are built using header rows.

As you can see, I have a main table with 1 row.  In column one, I have a table.  In column 2, I have a text box.  The idea is that the textbox fills the height of the table in column one.

This is fine for the initial view.  Other views of this report will hide Row 3.  When Row 3 is hidden, the Textbox stays the same size.  The desired behavior is to shrink the textbox in column two to match the new height of the table.  I assume it is actually the row height of the parent row that is not changing when the content changes.

Any ideas on how to get my desired affect?  I thought about making the default row size really small and expanding as necessary, but this is not desirable because the inner table should have explicit row heights.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?